# Table Export Jquery/JS not exporting html table data

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I tried to use 2 plugins to export html table data to xls or pdf file, the last plugin I tried is Table Export Jquery :
https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin

I downloaded the library and include it in my head part, I gave my html table an id, then i used this plugin to export to xls, when i click on the button where I linked the function, an xls file is downloading and that's correct, when I open it I get only some html codes of the html devider before the table :

I created a table :

```
<table  id="dvData" class="table table-hover">
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowsReports">
<td style="text-align:left">{{row.ReportType}}</td>
</table
```

Then the export :

XLS

This table is getting some data from my database using angularjs and laravel restful api controller, but it's exporting only html code in xls, blank page in pdf.

Anyone could help ? Thank you

Comment: maybe angular bring out an implicit data, so plugin cannot read content. you should create a method for get content as variable then convert

Comment: I tried to create a simple table without using angularjs with some static data, same problem.

Comment: track yourtags include resource, lacking some?

Comment: I include all my resources using drag and drop to avoid path error, I checked my console error log, it's empty. Even the first plugin I tried gave the same result

Comment: show your script, to check?

Comment: the only line you need : <a href="#"          onClick="$('dvData').tableExport({type:'xls',escape:'false'});">XLS </a>

Comment: change 'xls' to be 'excel'

Comment: Tried to change it to "excel"  now no html codes in the output, but blank excel file, no data

Comment: my mistake, the # is missed before the selected id (it's jquery) . Thank you for your help.